# Why is the icon so large in the menu bar in 23.04?

Tags: icons, 23.04

The icon size in the menu bar becomes unreasonably large after I upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04. Also, the alignment of the arrow seems to be off as well... Can refer to the screenshot below. Anyone knows the fix?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLyck.png)

Update:

- Not using any scaling. Just 100% scale with 1920*1080 resolution;
- Tried rebooting many times. The problem remains.
- Also tried logging using another user account. The problem remains.
- Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics (ICL GT2)

Comment: Include information on your graphics card and on the display settings you use: Settings - Displays, indicate whether you use scaling or not (add this to your question: use "edit"). Eliminate some causes by testing: disable custom extensions, reboot, see if the issue persists ;  temporarily create a new account, log in to that and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Just upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04 today, and the icons on the settings menu, and the login screen went super big. I don't know if it's related to any new release they did or something :S

Comment: @vanadium Info added.

Comment: @Shelton today I got it fixed after rebooting. (Yesterday rebooting did not improve anything). Give it a try, I think it was fixed. I didn't update anything by myself

Comment: @Mayday Mines still remains. I rolled back to 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I got everything fixed after latest update

just regular

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

here is what was updated:

```
2023-06-12 12:26:55 upgrade gnome-shell:amd64 43.1-0ubuntu1 44.1-0ubuntu1
2023-06-12 12:26:55 upgrade gnome-shell-common:all 43.1-0ubuntu1 44.1-0ubuntu1
2023-06-12 12:26:55 upgrade mutter-common:all 43.0-1ubuntu4 44.1-0ubuntu1
2023-06-12 12:26:55 upgrade gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 43.2-0ubuntu1 44.0-1
2023-06-12 12:26:55 upgrade libmozjs-102-0:amd64 102.11.0-0ubuntu0.23.04.1 102.12.0-0ubuntu0.23.04.1
```

Comment: in my case apt won't upgrade these packages and say they have been kept back