# Huge arrows in GNOME 43 Quick Settings icons

Tags: gnome, 23.04

I've just updated to Ubuntu 23.04 and I noticed that the new arrows on the Quick Settings icons (like Wi-Fi) are huge compared to the icons and with a different background colour. Also the volume icon is quite larger than the other ones. My screen scaling is normal (100%). Any idea what can be causing this?
(the texts are in Czech but you get the idea)

[image: Quick Settings]

Comment: I don't really have Ubuntu right now, probably go to the display settings and change the scale to a lower percentage? I'm not sure if it works Tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked for me:
[Why is the icon so large in the menu bar in 23.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471443/why-is-the-icon-so-large-in-the-menu-bar-in-23-04)

In summary, you just have to do a regular update:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And restart your system.

Comment: Thanks, another restart sorted it out.